# Finder search for filename never seems to work

Tags: finder, search

For instance, I have a file in `~/Downloads` called "Franz Kafka.pdf".  I know it is there:

```
ls -l *Kafka*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  mygroup  9369233 Aug 21  2021 Franz Kafka.pdf
```

Finder cannot find it.  Is there something wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you search for the document using Spotlight (press Command-Space and type `"Frank Kafka.pdf"`), does it work?

Comment: Is Downloads indexed by Spotlight? Check System Prefs/Spotlight/Privacy. If it's not listed there, try adding it, waiting a few seconds, then removing it again. It won't find it if it's not indexed - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1gE3.png